# CSS SVG on iphone

Tags: iphone, svg, responsive-design

I'm a newbie in code and my brother ask me to make a site for is wedding
My problem is  when i use media query it works on my computeur and my samsung phone but on iphone my  arrow get stuck on the left of my screen and i dont know why

```
svg {
  width: 75px;
  height: 65px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5%;
  
}
```

I tried to change the css  with padding-left but dont work on iphone and put media query on the arrow  but still dont work

Comment: Please add more of your code to the question in the form of a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We need to see the context. Anyway, you cannot use `display: flex` and related CSS properties on the SVG element. Use them on a parent HTML element.